# RobotFramework : No action after validation in a pop-up

Tags: html, angularjs, popup, robotframework

Here is the context:
I'm testing a delete function from an application. When the delete request is selected, a pop-up appears to confirm or not the act. When I click the [YES] button, the page is refreshed with the deleted item. For this, the code calls a function in a javascript file.

When I try to reproduce this action with Robot Framework, I manage to click on the [YES] button, the page is refreshed but the element supposed to be deleted is always present. It seems that Robot Framework is not going to automatically execute the delete javascript code.

My Robot Framework script :

```
#We wait for the confirmation pop-up to appear
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//div[@tabindex="-1"]
#Click on the [YES] button
Click Element    xpath=//button[@tabindex="1"]
```

The code of the pop-up:

```html
<div class="sweet-alert  showSweetAlert visible" tabindex="-1" data-custom-class="" data-has-cancel-button="true" data-has-confirm-button="true" data-allow-outside-click="false" data-has-done-function="true" data-animation="pop" data-timer="null" style="display: block; margin-top: -154px;"><div class="sa-icon sa-error" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-x-mark">
        <span class="sa-line sa-left"></span>
        <span class="sa-line sa-right"></span>
      </span>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-warning pulseWarning" style="display: block;">
      <span class="sa-body pulseWarningIns"></span>
      <span class="sa-dot pulseWarningIns"></span>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-info" style="display: none;"></div><div class="sa-icon sa-success" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sa-line sa-tip"></span>
      <span class="sa-line sa-long"></span>

      <div class="sa-placeholder"></div>
      <div class="sa-fix"></div>
    </div><div class="sa-icon sa-custom" style="display: none;"></div><h2>Are you sure you want to delete this item ?</h2>
    <p class="lead text-muted "></p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" tabindex="3" placeholder="" type="text">
      <span class="sa-input-error help-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> <span class="sa-help-text">Not valid</span>
      </span>
    </div><div class="sa-button-container">
      <button class="cancel btn btn-lg btn-default" tabindex="2" style="display: inline-block;">No</button>
      <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
        <button class="confirm btn btn-lg confirm-button-class" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block;">Yes</button><div class="la-ball-fall">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
```

And the javascript code :

```js
        function deleteTenant(tenant) {
            swal({
                    title: $filter('translate')('alerts.swal.DELETE_Q'),
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    type: "warning",
                    confirmButtonClass: "confirm-button-class",
                    confirmButtonText: $filter('translate')('alerts.swal.DELETE_CONFRIM'),
                    cancelButtonText: $filter('translate')('alerts.swal.DELETE_CANCEL'),
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel: true,
                    animation: true,
                    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
                },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        TenantsService.deleteTenant(tenant.id).then(function (result) {
                                if (result.status === 500 || result.status === 403) {
                                    ToastService.showError('Something went wrong !');
                                } else {
                                    $scope.tenants.splice($scope.tenants.indexOf(tenant), 1);
                                    ToastService.showSuccess('Tenant [' + tenant.name + '] deleted successfully');
                                    setPage(1);
                                }

                            })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                //console.log(err);
                            });

                    } else {}
                });

        }
```

I read different articles without finding a suitable solution.
I also traded with the developer of the project and it seems that it is a limit of Robot Framework.

A network trace after clicking the YES button :
`{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.1",
    "creator": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "62.0.3"
    },
    "browser": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "62.0.3"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2018-10-09T10:23:43.079+02:00",
        "id": "page_1",
        "title": "smart tracking",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": -31330,
          "onLoad": -31319
        }
      }
    ],
    "entries": [
      {
        "pageref": "page_1",
        "startedDateTime": "2018-10-09T10:23:43.079+02:00",
        "request": {
          "bodySize": 0,
          "method": "DELETE",
          "url": "https://127.0.0.1:9000/admin/v0/tenants/583",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "127.0.0.1:9000"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://127.0.0.1:9000/"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
              "value": "71dee234-01f2-4722-9c8d-9856885238ca"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": "XSRF-TOKEN=71dee234-01f2-4722-9c8d-9856885238ca; X-XSRF-SECURE-TOKEN=71dee234-01f2-4722-9c8d-9856885238ca; X-TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzkxMTY1NzcsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImJpbGwiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX0dQIl0sImp0aSI6Ijc0Njc0MThlLWYyMjAtNGFjYi05ODIwLTFjY2I3ZWQ5YjljNSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImJyb3dzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJleHRlcm5hbCJdfQ.cT0BEUCvITaa6M1t3rY7LKWfZ87u6-uZPji0uwMXj5y1ppnfX5-vGR81yRc-gMPBl-3ULARC_MaaFpfXn1EtD5vjau6mqWMlZBCzPR9GT7XystxhdpZbAENbsiAaVbu37w2TG1qimvL402Brh8xoBXBb4HG1oadOWv_MlOhIyeWdZ7RrBpAcpK2cTcmWvr1RRDOxorVT_vjiLe01sIh2-M4DuvhmqK-oHHZssMulIuZIOTClIMtyY2Y7vY0Wik1eJ-hQ0mkjBT_ae0VMXPv4ESnEj0QNTRi5zciV24MIAtDlnAhEm3lk2MGA0nX2e4GHvD8P8RSy8DHeSY68D7VvwQ; SESSION-ID=245295400"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "XSRF-TOKEN",
              "value": "71dee234-01f2-4722-9c8d-9856885238ca"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-XSRF-SECURE-TOKEN",
              "value": "71dee234-01f2-4722-9c8d-9856885238ca"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-TOKEN",
              "value": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzkxMTY1NzcsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImJpbGwiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX0dQIl0sImp0aSI6Ijc0Njc0MThlLWYyMjAtNGFjYi05ODIwLTFjY2I3ZWQ5YjljNSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImJyb3dzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJleHRlcm5hbCJdfQ.cT0BEUCvITaa6M1t3rY7LKWfZ87u6-uZPji0uwMXj5y1ppnfX5-vGR81yRc-gMPBl-3ULARC_MaaFpfXn1EtD5vjau6mqWMlZBCzPR9GT7XystxhdpZbAENbsiAaVbu37w2TG1qimvL402Brh8xoBXBb4HG1oadOWv_MlOhIyeWdZ7RrBpAcpK2cTcmWvr1RRDOxorVT_vjiLe01sIh2-M4DuvhmqK-oHHZssMulIuZIOTClIMtyY2Y7vY0Wik1eJ-hQ0mkjBT_ae0VMXPv4ESnEj0QNTRi5zciV24MIAtDlnAhEm3lk2MGA0nX2e4GHvD8P8RSy8DHeSY68D7VvwQ"
            },
            {
              "name": "SESSION-ID",
              "value": "245295400"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "headersSize": 1127
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 500,
          "statusText": "Internal Server Error",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "ecstatic-3.2.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-content-type-options",
              "value": "nosniff"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-xss-protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
            },
            {
              "name": "pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "expires",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-frame-options",
              "value": "DENY"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-application-context",
              "value": "application:8443"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "transfer-encoding",
              "value": "chunked"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Tue, 09 Oct 2018 08:23:43 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "connection",
              "value": "close"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "size": 346,
            "text": "{\"timestamp\":1539073423358,\"status\":500,\"error\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"exception\":\"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException\",\"message\":\"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement\",\"path\":\"/admin/v0/tenants/583\"}"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 415,
          "bodySize": 761
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 2,
          "dns": 0,
          "connect": 2,
          "ssl": 33,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 246,
          "receive": 0
        },
        "time": 283,
        "_securityState": "secure",
        "serverIPAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "connection": "9000"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Would you please have a workaround to add to my Robot Framework script ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Well, first and foremost Robotframework doesn't execute your javascript - it instructs SE to tell the browser to treat the button as clicked, and it's the browser that executes the JS - if the page's handlers are coded correct. The full flow actually is: your case keword -> RF SeleniumLibrary -> selenium lib-> the browser's driver -> the browser; if there's a failure to execute a JS, it's hardly the robotframework.

Comment: In all seriousness - are you sure the call clicks the "yes" button? I see the locator and it looks correct, but have you tried a different one (like based on its text) - to be sure it's not clicking the "no" one? Does the behavior confirm with the expected one when "yes" is clicked? Is the request sent from the browser to the server the one  that's is expected when "yes" is clicked? Are there any server logs what request was received/what was the user's action?

Comment: With the developer of our project we spent a long time exchanging and testing to verify that it was the right button that was selected. When RF simulates press [YES], a green pop-up appears temporarily as the action of suppresson has been done; as in the operation without RF. At the request DELETE, I receive a code 200 like what everything is OK

Comment: Sorry, the DELETE request does not appear in the network log after clicking YES through RF. It appears well without going through RF.

Comment: If the request is not sent out, then I'd be suspecious of the button press. As automation if often faster than a human, add some temporary wait steps in your code to verify if timing is an issue. If not, then add some code to the button script to print someting in the console to validate it is actually pressed.

Comment: I tried a long delay of 30 seconds. But nothing changes. Press YES on the Robot Framework is validated and confirmed but the delete action is not done.
For information, it works very well with a python script using Webdriver :
`elem = WebDriverWait (driver, 30) .until (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "// button [@ class = 'confirm btn -btn -lg confirm-button-class']")))  
elem.click ()`
How to make it work with Robot Framework?

Comment: Sorry to be "that guy" - but the xpath in your last comment is different from the one in the question; what happens when you use this one in the RF script?

Comment: @Todor I don't know how to execute this python code with RobotFramework keywords

Comment: No, my point is different, not the code, but - in your question the xpath is `//button[@tabindex="1"]`, but in the code you cite in the previous comment as working it is `//button[@class = 'confirm btn-btn-lg confirm-button-class']`. What happens when you try with the 2nd xpath?

Comment: @Todor : I encounter exactly the same problem. Would there be a set of keywords to force Robot Framework to execute the Javascript code that allows to delete the element ?

Comment: `Execute Javascript`, and you pass whatever js code you want to be ran in the browser.

Comment: @Todor Here is the line of code executed just after clicking the YES button :  `$scope.tenants.splice($scope.tenants.indexOf(tenant), 1);`.  By cons, I don't know Javascript. Could you, please, help me to write the correct syntax behind the keyword 'Run JavaScript' ?

Comment: Maybe a track ... I added the AngularJSLibrary library and I now have this error :   JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: angular.element(...).injector(...) is undefined @Todor

Comment: @Todor : I added a network trace after the RF simulation of the click on the YES button. I removed the AngularJSLibrary library because the error seems to come from elsewhere